# 8-puzzle in 12 steps

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, sliding-blocks

This quiz is about the 8-puzzle. It is a board with 9 spaces. There are 8 tiles with the numbers 1 through 8. One space is empty (`.`). You slide the tiles around the board, but only numbers next to the empty space can be slid into the empty space.

The starting configuration is

> $$               %  Preview
> . \:\: 8 \:\: 7 \\ %   . 8 7
> 6 \:\: 5 \:\: 4 \\ %   6 5 4
> 3 \:\: 2 \:\: 1    %   3 2 1
> $$

The end configuration is

> $$               %  Preview
> . \:\: 1 \:\: 2 \\ %   . 1 2
> 3 \:\: 4 \:\: 5 \\ %   3 4 5
> 6 \:\: 7 \:\: 8    %   6 7 8
> $$

The goal is to get the board from the start configuration to the end configuration in 12 steps. Sliding two tiles at the same time counts as two steps.

Comment: I fixed the formatting for you. Welcome to the site!

Comment: What do you mean by a "step"? Surely to get each of the 1, 2, 7, 8 tiles to its new position will take three steps, using up the twelve already without even fixing the 3, 4, 5, 6 tiles.

Comment: i meant a 'move'

Comment: If, for example, you slide the 8 and 7 tiles in the starting configuration to the left at the same time, would it count as 1 step or 2?

Comment: it would count as 2 steps

Comment: Do you know the solution?

Comment: No, i don't know

Comment: As Randal'Thor mentioned, it's not possible if you count a step as moving a single tile. I verified this with a brute-force algorithm on this site: http://tristanpenman.com/demos/n-puzzle/

Comment: Step 1: Open the frame. Step 2: Dump out all the tiles....

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to do this in 12 steps. In fact, a simple argument shows that at least 20 steps are necessary:

  Tiles 1 and 8 need to be swapped. They are however a distance of 3 moves apart, so each tile needs to be moved at least 3 times. Similarly, tiles 2 and 7 also each need 3 moves to reach their goal locations. So these 4 tiles together need at least 12 moves to be solved.
  Tiles 3 and 6 need to be swapped and are each 1 move away from their goal location, but since they cannot pass through each other, one of the tiles needs to temporarily move to a different row, so together these 2 tiles need at least 4 moves. Similarly tiles 4 and 5 also need 4 moves.

I have run this position through a solver, and it actually turns out that the fewest number of moves to solve it is 30. Even if shifting two tiles at the same time is considered a single move, it needs 21 moves.

> ```
>  . 1 2   3 1 2   3 1 2   3 1 .   3 . 1 
>  3 4 5   . 4 5   4 5 .   4 5 2   4 5 2 
>  6 7 8   6 7 8   6 7 8   6 7 8   6 7 8 
>  
>  3 5 1   3 5 1   . 5 1   5 . 1   5 7 1 
>  4 7 2   4 7 2   3 7 2   3 7 2   3 6 2 
>  6 . 8   . 6 8   4 6 8   4 6 8   4 . 8 
>  
>  5 7 1   5 7 .   5 . 7   5 6 7   5 6 7 
>  3 6 2   3 6 1   3 6 1   3 8 1   3 8 1 
>  4 8 .   4 8 2   4 8 2   4 . 2   . 4 2 
>  
>  . 6 7   6 . 7   6 8 7   6 8 7   6 8 7 
>  5 8 1   5 8 1   5 4 1   5 4 1   5 4 . 
>  3 4 2   3 4 2   3 . 2   3 2 .   3 2 1 
>  
>  6 8 7   . 8 7 
>  . 5 4   6 5 4 
>  3 2 1   3 2 1
> ```

Comment: It is well known that these two positions need the largest number of moves - assuming the `0` is in the same corner before and after.

Comment: @WhatsUp Not true. There are two positions that are at distance 31 from the starting position. See for example [here](http://w01fe.com/blog/2009/01/the-hardest-eight-puzzle-instances-take-31-moves-to-solve/), but turn them upside-down for this question's upside-down starting position.

Comment: I did say *assuming the 0 is in the same corner before and after*...

Comment: @WhatsUp Sorry, you're right. The only ones at 31 don't have the blank in the same place as the start.

Comment: Several decades ago we played this game in our primary school, at the age of ~7. Our math teacher told us the fact that, if one only exchanges the positions of two numbers and keeps the remaining, then it's unsolvable. This might be easy with a bit of group theory, but it was amazing how he managed to explain it to children of age 7!